# How to get BLE device ID on ESP32

Tags: bluetooth, uuid, esp32

I develop a Cordova application, which connects to ESP32 board via bluetooth or wifi. I use BLEDevice and BLEServer objects on ESP32 board. Once everything is setup on ESP32 side, it starts advertising

```
BLEAdvertising *pAdvertising = pServer->getAdvertising();
pAdvertising->start();
```

When I scan for BT devices with my Cordova application, I can see the ESP32 device with this information:

```
id = "25DAB436-A5F8-2303-5F84-8B2DCE8581AE";
name = ModelCommander;
rssi = "-46";
state = disconnected;
```

The id attribute ( "25DAB436-A5F8-2303-5F84-8B2DCE8581AE" in this example ) is used for creating BT connection from the Cordova application to the ESP32 device. Is there a way, how to get the ID using ESP32 code? I can only get BT MAC adress using

```
BLEDevice::getAddress()
```